# fixed footer effect in CSS (like fixed image)

Tags: html, css, footer, fixed

I would like to create footer effect just like on [this](http://www.dotcomweavers.com/) site. I think I need a wrapper for my content and then add footer.

So structure would be like:

```
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS like:

```
.footer{
width: 100%;
}

.footer-content{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 0;
}
.content{
z-index: 9999 !important;
background-color: #fff;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 600px; //height of my full footer
}
```

However this doesn't make this effect. Please help and sorry for my english.

Comment: Amir, is right. Also, your code should work.

Comment: Amir texted about fixed background image - I want whole footer fixed effect (with content).

Comment: it's very close, here is a fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/jrgaoztp/

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you'll need to make the footer fixed and have the content scroll above it.

A rough example of the CSS would be:

```
.content {
    position: relative;    /* required for z-index to work */
    z-index: 2;            /* bring above footer */
    margin-bottom: 100px;  /* the height of the footer */
}


.footer {
    position: fixed; /* fix in position */
    z-index: 1;      /* bring below content */
    bottom: 0;       /* anchor to bottom of screen */
    left: 0;         /* go full width */
    width: 100%;     /* go full width */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please check this code

HTML

```
<div class="content">
  <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-content">
      <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.footer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
}

.footer-content{
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.content{
  z-index: 9999 !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1500px;
  margin-bottom: 600px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```

A sample
[Fixed footer effect in CSS](http://codepen.io/anayarojo/pen/KrkaqK)